# Privately publish Android Apps without using Gsuite

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-workspace

My requirement is to privately publish an android app for an organization without using Gsuite. Also after uploading the app for first time I want to update the app like Google Play Store. Is there any option available to do this?

Comment: You can just release the app as a private beta and open it only to the members of the organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HockeyApp is a good option. You can crate your own distribution groups and also detect and prompt users to update to new versions using HockeyApp Sdk integration in your app.

Comment: I have used HockeyApp. It works fine. Any other suggestions?

Comment: As someone mentioned in the comments : you could use alpha or beta channels to distribute your app to selected audiences.